# Log event processing query that calculates the time between events

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2014:

I am trying to build a query that calculates the time between specific events in a log table.

For example, consider the following table:

```
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| PK_INT_ID | EmpID | Name | Event | DateTime         |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 1         | 5     | Mike | In    | 2016-10-12 14:05 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 2         | 4     | Jane | In    | 2016-10-12 14:08 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 3         | 4     | Jane | Out   | 2016-10-12 15:08 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 4         | 5     | Mike | Out   | 2016-10-12 16:05 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 5         | 5     | Mike | In    | 2016-10-13 08:15 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 6         | 5     | Mike | In    | 2016-10-13 08:30 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 7         | 4     | Jane | In    | 2016-10-13 08:31 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 8         | 4     | Jane | Out   | 2016-10-13 16:31 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 9         | 5     | Mike | In    | 2016-10-14 08:10 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
| 10        | 5     | Mike | Out   | 2016-10-14 15:10 |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+------------------+
```

The query I am trying to create needs to calculate the following output:

```
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
| Date       | EmpID | Name | Hours Worked |
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
| 2016-10-12 | 4     | Jane | 1            |
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
| 2016-10-12 | 5     | Mike | 2            |
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
| 2016-10-13 | 4     | Jane | 8            |
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
| 2016-10-13 | 5     | Mike | NULL         |
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
| 2016-10-14 | 4     | Mike | 7            |
+------------+-------+------+--------------+
```

What is the most efficient query and indexes strategy to get this output?

Is there any special pattern name for this type of log event processing queries?

Comment: can there be multiple in/out combinations in a day for a given empid? if so, what should the criteria be for calculating the hours worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is one in-out combination per empid per day, you can use

```
select cast(datetime as date) dt,empid,name,
datediff(hour, 
         max(case when event = 'In' then datetime end),
         max(case when event = 'Out' then datetime end)
         ) hours_worked
from t
group by cast(datetime as date),empid,name
```

The computed column (hours_worked) would be `null` in case there are 2 in's or 2 out's on a given day.

Comment: The answer is correct but the final comment is false. In case there is more than a single combination of IN-OUT, the results would represent the last combination. If the last operation is IN, then we would get a negative results representing the difference between the last IN and the previous OUT

Comment: i meant to say 2 in's only or 2 out's only.